# What steps are required to increase performance of Android application?

Tags: android, performance, testing, live

Please let me know, how we can increase performance of android app.

Comment: Just run the `Code Inspector`, fix all the issues, and you're done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One check would be if your app is leaking any memory

you can check this with adb command memifo. More information about it at->

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html#ViewingAllocations

Tracking down memory leaks
http://macgyverdev.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-track-down-memory-leaks.html